# Variable LIMIT from other SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql, join, limit

I got a table `av` with the columns `ID, amount`.

Also got a `users` table with the columns `ID, timestamp`

Now each voucher relates to the `first x` users (ordered by timestamp), where `x` is the `amount` value of the certain voucher.

I did a [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=56bd801db60b012a301f06d8172659d2) with a small example

My expected result:

```
voucherID    userID
11           10
12           10
12           11
```

For better understanding:

An admin creates a voucher that is supposed to go to the first X users registered. Each voucher has a different X

Comment: What is a relationship on voucherID on uSerID?

Comment: You did a great job of setting up dbfiddle. In relation to @Bulfaitelo's question, can you explain why/how voucher 11 and 12 are associated with user 10?

Comment: My result tuples are supposed to be inserted into a new table which links `users` and `av`. @zedfoxus Well voucher 11 has amount 1, which means first 1 users from the table. Voucher 12 has amount 2, which means first 2 users from the table.

Comment: I think the ideal would be to have a table between these two to make this relationship

Comment: The thing is that there's no relation between those two tables. An admin creates a voucher that is supposed to go to the first X users registered. Each voucher has a different X.

Comment: Ah, I get it. I cannot think of a SQL query with MySQL that can help you. I can think of a stored procedure you could write for that, though. If you are familiar with stored procedures, go ahead and give it a shot. If not, jot a message here and someone can help you.

Comment: Haven't heard of stored procedures yet, but I'll try look into it if there's no easier way of doing it.

Comment: I think @Bulfaitelo is right, you need a junction table to _create_ a relationship between them. It would store the `id` from one table and the `id` from the other table on the same row then you can easily `join` them.

Comment: @EternalHour The junction table you are talking about is the one I'm trying to fill here with my result. As I explained to zedfoxus in a comment, there is no relation between those tables until I create it by using the command I'm trying to figure out.

Comment: Yeah, after looking into it more I see what you're trying to do. Thinking a stored procedure is the best way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
with
u as (
  select userID, timestampMock, 
    row_number() over (order by timestampMock) as rn
  from users
)
select
  av.voucherID, u.userID
from av
join u on u.rn <= av.amount
order by av.voucherID, u.userID
```

I tested it in your dbfiddle and its result is:

```
voucherID   userID
---------   ------
11          10
12          10
12          11
```

Comment: This is a nice query. I recall now that MySQL 8 has CTEs. +1